# File manipulation python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, text, transactions

The file expressions.txt must be loaded into the program. The structure of the file is thus each line an expression of an elementary operation (addition, subtraction, multiplication or division), such as for example:

You need to write a program to show you that file line by line, apply it once, and write the result, along with the corresponding expression, to the file output.txt. Pay attention to the newline character and when opening and closing files.

Layout of the output.txt file:

Comment: Can you include the layout of the output.txt file and the code you have so far?

Comment: in the program I have to enter two files for it to read :

Comment: file.txt : 20 + 3
12 - 4 
12 * 4 
20 / 5 
and output.txt 20 + 3=23
12 - 4=8
12 * 4=48
20 / 5=4.0

Comment: I started a code but I don't know how to make it read those files and I don't know if the code is correct

Comment: Please include the examples in the question itself so that it would be clear for others to get an idea.

Comment: can you help me with a code idea?

Answer (score -1):

If you have any questions related to the code, just ask:

```
# Open the file 'expressions.txt' in read mode
with open('expressions.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Open the file 'output.txt' in write mode
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as g:
        # Read the file line by line
        for line in f:
            # Strip the newline character from the line
            line = line.strip()
            # Split the line into the operand, operator, and second operand
            operand, operator, second_operand = line.split()
            # Convert the operand and second operand to floats
            operand = float(operand)
            second_operand = float(second_operand)
            # Initialize a variable to store the result of the operation
            result = 0
            # Perform the operation and store the result
            if operator == '+':
                result = operand + second_operand
            elif operator == '-':
                result = operand - second_operand
            elif operator == '*':
                result = operand * second_operand
            elif operator == '/':
                result = operand / second_operand
            # Write the result and expression to the file 'output.txt'
            g.write(f'{line} = {result}\n')
```

edit:

You need to have the expressions.txt in the same folder where you start the .py file. The output will be created in the same path as well.

Also, I have rewritten the code to make it easier to understand.

If you tell me how you try to run your file, I can assist further.

Comment: when I run the code, nothing appears

Comment: shouldn't my files be opened?

Comment: I managed to make it work. My mistake was that I did not put the directory where the output file is located correctly . Thank you very much for your help